# PsychoPy - Workaround for (still ongoing) pyglet memory leak affecting text components displayed at frame-level

Tags: psychopy

I too have run across the infamous pyglet memory leak, that occurs when one needs to update text components at the frame level (with a text variable typically computed in a separate code component, also at frame level).

The leak/bug crashes a running script with an error message of the sort:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.83.04-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\window.py", line 541, in flip
        thisStim.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.83.04-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\text.py", line 603, in draw
        self._pygletTextObj.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\font\__init__.py", line 565, in draw
        self._layout.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 852, in draw
        self.batch.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\__init__.py", line 544, in draw
        func()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\__init__.py", line 476, in <lambda>
        (lambda d, m: lambda: d.draw(m))(domain, mode))

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\vertexdomain.py", line 313, in draw
        glDrawArrays(mode, starts[0], sizes[0])

WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000010
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method Server.__del__ of <pyolib.server.Server object at 0x0EFB3670>> ignored
```

I know the PsychoPy community has linked this to a memory leak in pyglet that was meant to have been fixed around April 2016 according to [this](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues/66/memory-leak-in-fonttext) thread. I [downloaded](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/downloads) the latest version of Pyglet (which is v1.2.4 - released apparently in Sep 2015, so before the supposed fix of the leak) and replaced its contents under `c:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\`. However, this did not fix my problem.

Unfortunately, my experiment does not make sense if I give up the frame-wise computation that feeds the text component.

An older [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psychopy-users/BlYHCBIlVhc) that I found suggested the following workaround: in the code component that computes frame-wise the value of the text variable being displayed, only assign this variable a new value if that new value actually differs from the previous value. However, even after changing my code component this way, the pyglet error still pops up.

Assuming the bug was fixed in Pyglet, is it not v1.2.4 that reflects this fix, and should it not be updated by overwriting the contents of `c:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\pyglet\`  (maintaining the original folder structure)?

Assuming the bug was in fact NOT fixed in Pyglet, can anyone suggested a different workaround that I can try to make my PsychoPy expt not crash?

Many thanks indeed for your help.

(Apologies for the double post both here and on the psychopy group; will update both threads as soon as there is a response on the other, to avoid people wasting time with double answers).

Comment: The most extreme (unsatisfactory) solution would be to simply run small chunks of the experiment at a time - small enough that the memory leak doesn't cause the crash. That is, if you can find a way to display the desired conditions with these shutdown/startup breaks in between.

Comment: The expt crashes after only a few trials, therefore an experiment chunk that would not crash would be too small to make sense :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use TextBox instead of TextStim. To do that, one first defines a stimulus object in a code component (under "begin routine"), such as

```
textbox = visual.TextBox(window=win, 
                         text='Something',
                         font_size=21,
                         font_color=[-1,-1,1], 
                         size=(1.9, .3),
                         pos=(0.0, 0.25), 
                         grid_horz_justification='center',
                         units='norm')
```

then, perhaps under the "every frame" tab, one uses code to customise & call upon the thus-defined textbox, with syntax as found on http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/textbox.html