# Psychopy/Python - access violation reading 0x00000010

Tags: python, psychopy

I use Win7, PsychoPy version 1.90.2, but the same error is also for 3.0.0b11, Standard Standalone.

When running my experiment, it crashes at certain (variable) point:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Martin\PsychoPy\FingerTTv3\FingerTTv3_lastrun.py", line 356, in <module>
    win.flip()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\window.py", line 684, in flip
    thisStim.draw()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\text.py", line 800, in draw
    self._pygletTextObj.draw()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\font\text.py", line 557, in draw
    self._layout.draw()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 897, in draw
    self._batch.draw()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\__init__.py", line 560, in draw
    func()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\__init__.py", line 492, in <lambda>
    (lambda d, m: lambda: d.draw(m))(domain, mode))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\vertexdomain.py", line 316, in draw
    glDrawArrays(mode, starts[0], sizes[0])
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000010
```

Usually 5-7 minutes after the start. I tried multiple runs, reworked whole experiment (3x), tried to isolate the issue. It crashes even when I have only the "trial-feedback" loop, so there should be the issue.

**Description of the experiment**
It has two routines and two loops

Routine: *Trial* [Screen for "Trial" routine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvqKP.jpg)

Here, eight text items (digits) are presented, aligned horizontally at precise location. Also, there is one polygon (*frame*,  square shape). The location of the square changes each keypress so it is under next text item (digit), sequentially from right to left and again.

The Position [x,y] of the moving *frame* set during every repeat from a xlsx file (column with name "Posit"), each trial, the position is updated:

> $eval(Posit)

The positions in the xlsx column "Posit" look like this (normalized distances =-1,1):

**Posit**
(-0.42, 0.2)
(-0.3, 0.2)
(-0.18, 0.2)
(-0.06, 0.2)
(0.06, 0.2)
(0.18, 0.2)
(0.3, 0.2)
(0.42, 0.2)

The _key_press_ is just to record the pressed key and decide whether it is correct.
The last item is a picture, which is present there. Size 709x353pix and 47.7kB.

Reoutine: *FB* [Screen for "FB" routine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7ZhM.jpg)

The second routine  is just a feedback with 0.1s duration. The picture stays the same (to avoid blinking). There is also this moving frame (which just changes color to red). And a bit of code, which is just to omit this red warning when the trial is correct. If not correct, then a variable Error increases by 1

> if key_press.corr:
>       continueRoutine = False
>
> else:
>       Error = Error+1

The _trials_Keypress_ loop makes the *frame* to jump to the positions from xlsx. The second lool *trials* is just for blocking.

Please, any idea what is wrong? I got such error also in other experiments, sometimes it was enough to rework it or rebuild it again. Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you tried running it on other computers? Just to know if this is specific to your computer (I suspect that it is). If so, try updating your graphics drivers from the vendors website. In any case, the full set of experiment files will be helpful to debug this. It is probably better to post it on https://discourse.psychopy.org since this may require some back-and-forth. Delete this question or paste the Discourse link here for future interested visitors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I found a post (see below), indicating that his might be due to memory leaks pertaining to textStim item. I tried to change them for a picture and the problem is gone! See more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101759/psychopy-workaround-for-still-ongoing-pyglet-memory-leak-affecting-text-comp?fbclid=IwAR1xzvTcVXsS2ExPIspMCWgq60qYsBLQ6mSQMLwQlTsZ1Jq3vI5qVvNbHes